# SimpleMembership CreateUserAndAccount IDENTITY_INSERT error on custom user table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I'm trying to use my own Users table for simplememership, adding some data to it. based on the sample here - http://blog.osbornm.com/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp.net-webpages/
I've created a table with this model:

```
 [Table("MyUsers")]
```

public class MyUsers

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int UserId { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Gender { get; set; }
public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
```

I'm initializing it :

```
  WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyConnection", "MyUsers", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

and on registration I call:

```
  WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new MyUsers {DOB = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-31),Email = "my@mymail.com",Gender = "Male",UserName = model.UserName});
```

But -  I get this error:
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'MyUsers' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

not sure how to set this off in VS2010, but I'm not sure why I even get this error, ans what should I fix.

Help appreciated, I'm trying to test if i can move  a legacy asp.net project to MVC.

Thansk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found my issue - it was with CreateUserAndAccount, I used a class that matched all fields in the table, including the key. shouldn't be this way.
this works:

```
 WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password,new  {Gender="Mal",DOB = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1),Email="mymy@trtr.com" });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is built an extension off of the base users table. Because of this the `UserId` column **should not** be an auto incremented column. It's going to try and `INSERT` the actual ID from the base users table as the foreign key.

Comment: Thanks, but if I'll remove this, I need to set the ID myself? and then the same id will be user in the webpages_Membership ? Is there a good way to get a new ID besides querying the User table?

Comment: @GuyV, the ID that the framework is trying to INSERT is the unique user id. You don't have a reason for another ID honestly do you? That ID won't ever be duplicated and this isn't a one-to-many table is it? Isn't it a one-to-one table? And no, you should have to set the ID yourself - that's why it's failing - the framework is trying to set the ID.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm missing something basic. If I'll look at the UserProfile table that the template will auto generate for me, I see it has increment. I tried to replace this table with my own, and add the additional params in CreateUserAndAccount.  so if I understand correctly, the userid in my table should be inserted. ( I also try to let the UserProfile table get genreted ann add columns to this table, but got the same issue).  BTW - remoding thekey form my table, results in the userid always set to 0, hence failing to insert on the second user.